# Dynamic and non-dynamic routes in sidebar

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a budgeting app for my wife and I to use and to learn react. My app has a sidebar and a top nav. The sidebar has a dynamically built list of accounts as well as a homepage which will shows some spending reports. Selecting one of the accounts loads a `Transactions` component which renders the transactions for each account.

[image]

When clicking on the `Home` button, the `Transactions` component in the main pane should be replaced with my `HomePage` component, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make this work with react-router. Hopefully that makes sense.

Here's how the sidebar is currently built:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import classnames from 'classnames';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faMoneyCheck, faCreditCard, faPiggyBank, faHome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const API = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/';

class AccountNavigation extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      checkingAccounts: [],
      savingsAccounts: [],
      creditCardAccounts: [],
      selectedAccount: null,
    }
  }

  handleAccountSelect = (event) => {
    // console.log(event)
    this.props.handleAccountSelect(event.target.value)
    this.setState({
      selectedAccount: event.target.value
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    }, () => {
      // console.log(this.state);
    });

    axios.get(API).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        data: response.data,
        checkingAccounts: response.data.checking,
        savingsAccounts: response.data.savings,
        creditCardAccounts: response.data.credit_card,
        isLoading: false,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      checkingAccounts,
      savingsAccounts,
      creditCardAccounts
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <nav className="no-col-padding bg-light col-md-2 sidebar d-none d-md-block">
        <div className="sidebar-sticky">
          <h6 className="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1">
            <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} /> Home</span>
          </h6>
          <h6 className="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1">
            <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMoneyCheck} /> Checking</span>
          </h6>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
              { checkingAccounts.map((account) => {
                var btnClass = classnames({
                  btn: true,
                  'btn-link': true,
                  'nav-link': true,
                  'active': this.state.selectedAccount === account.id.toString()
                });

                  return (
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <button eventKey={account.id} type="button" className={btnClass} onClick={this.handleAccountSelect} value={account.id}>
                        { account.account_name }
                      </button>
                    </li>
                  )
              })}
          </ul>
          <h6 className="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1">
            <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCreditCard} /> Credit Cards</span>
          </h6>
          <ul className="nav flex-column">
              { creditCardAccounts.map((account) => {
                var btnClass = classnames({
                  btn: true,
                  'btn-link': true,
                  'nav-link': true,
                  'active': this.state.selectedAccount === account.id.toString()
                });

                  return (
                    <li className="nav-item" activeClassName="active">
                      <button eventKey={account.id} type="button" className={btnClass} onClick={this.handleAccountSelect} value={account.id}>
                        { account.account_name }
                      </button>
                    </li>
                  )
              })}
          </ul>
          <h6 className="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1">
            <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPiggyBank} /> Savings</span>
          </h6>
          <ul className="nav flex-column">
              { savingsAccounts.map((account) => {
                var btnClass = classnames({
                  btn: true,
                  'btn-link': true,
                  'nav-link': true,
                  'active': this.state.selectedAccount === account.id.toString()
                });

                  return (
                    <li className="nav-item" activeClassName="active">
                      <button eventKey={account.id} type="button" className={btnClass} onClick={this.handleAccountSelect} value={account.id}>
                        { account.account_name }
                      </button>
                    </li>
                  )
              })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  };
}

export default AccountNavigation;
```

And my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import AccountNavigation from './components/AccountNavigation';
import Transactions from './components/Transactions';
import TransactionButtons from './components/TransactionButtons';

import Header from './components/Header';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      selectedAccount: null,
      showTransactionForm: false
    }

    this.handleAccountSelect = this.handleAccountSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleAccountSelect = (accountId) => {
    // console.log("print handleAccountSelect called")
    // console.log(accountId)
    this.setState({selectedAccount: accountId});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* <Header /> */}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
          <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Budget Zen</a>
            {/* <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"> */}
          <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
            <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <AccountNavigation
              handleAccountSelect = {this.handleAccountSelect} />
            <main role="main" className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
                <div className="col-10">
                  <Transactions
                    selectedAccount = {this.state.selectedAccount}
                    showTransactionForm = {this.state.showTransactionForm}/>
                </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}

export default App;
```

I've looked at a lot of examples, but none of them deal with a sidebar that use both react-router and some links that share the same component.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue you are facing? It looks like this is just a `home` route and another with dynamic `/:transactionId`

Comment: Maybe I'm being thrown off because I'm currently using handlers and state to switch between accounts and I want to have routes for my HomePage and future pages. I haven't implemented react-router at all. Is it possible to implement my account switching using react-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For react router, to [render a dynamic route](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params), you would need to pass in an ID as URL parameter, in your case assuming that is `accountId`, the Route config in `App.js` would be:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import AccountNavigation from './components/AccountNavigation';
import Transactions from './components/Transactions';
import TransactionButtons from './components/TransactionButtons';

import Header from './components/Header';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showTransactionForm: false
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
            <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Budget Zen</a>
              {/* <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"> */}
            <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
              <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <AccountNavigation
                handleAccountSelect = {this.handleAccountSelect} />
              <main role="main" className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
                  <div className="col-10">
                    <Switch>
                      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                      <Route path="/:accountId" render={(props) => (<Transaction showTransactionForm = {this.state.showTransactionForm} {...props}/>)} />
                    </Switch>
                  </div>
              </main>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </BrowserRouter> 
     );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Inside `AccountNavigation`, you can route with:

```
  handleAccountSelect = (event) => {
    this.props.history.push(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      selectedAccount: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

Remember that `AccountNavigation` is not in the `Route` and you would need to wrap it with [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to receive `history` prop:

```
export default withRouter(AccountNavigation);
```

Inside `Transaction` component, you can received the selected `accountId` with:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { accountId } = this.props.match.params;
}
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Thank you!